# JSON Deserialize JSON.Net C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

**UPDATE:**

I have a **listbox** which has to be filled with JSON data received from webservice. I successfully retrieve the JSON data and the listbox is filled with listitems but each listitem does not show the value of the JSON data parsed and shows it blank.

Code follows:

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://foo.com/w.php"));
    }

    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string json = e.Result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            PortfolioResult results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PortfolioResult>(json);
            lstPortfolio.ItemsSource = results.results;
        }
    }

    public class Portfolios
    {
        public string PortfolioID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string IsEnable { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string DateAdded { get; set; }
        public string DateUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public class PortfolioResult
    {
        public List<Portfolios> results { get; set; }
    }
```

The XAML:

```
    <ListBox Name="lstPortfolio" Foreground="Black" Margin="12,76,12,12" Grid.Row="1" Width="456" Height="680">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="auto" Width="456" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="145" Width="460">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35">
                            <TextBlock Width="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="ID:" FontSize="22" Height="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="{Binding Path=PortfolioID}" FontSize="20" Height="40"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35">
                            <TextBlock Width="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="Name:" FontSize="22" Height="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontSize="20" Height="40"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35">
                            <TextBlock Width="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="Details:" FontSize="22" Height="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="{Binding Path=Comment}" FontSize="20" Height="40"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35">
                            <TextBlock Width="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="Date:" FontSize="22" Height="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF527104" Text="{Binding Path=DateUpdated}" FontSize="20" Height="40"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF527104" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Should `lstPortfolio.ItemsSource` not be in the `webClient_DownloadStringCompleted` method?

Comment: When I insert lstPortfolio.ItemsSource there it gives the following error: **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property**

Comment: `lstPortfolio.ItemsSource = results;` ?

Comment: The error was because of the keyword **static** prior to the function. I removed static and added this line: `lstPortfolio.ItemsSource = results.results;`
Now it loads the listitems but does not load the textbox with JSON values. Any idea?

Comment: And if you examine `results.results` with the debugger that looks OK?

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: @rishiJasapara Please show raw JSON you get from server.

Comment: I figured the way out. There were a lot of raw content in JSON data generated. I printed everything and eliminated everything one by one. And then implemented for each loop for every JSON record. `foreach (var rr in resultsJSON.results)
{ 
lstAbout3.Items.Add(resultsJSON.results[i].result); 
i++;
}`